# get last entered value insert from table in trigger for non auto incremental primary key

Tags: mysql

I am very new to mysql databases and my query is I have written a trigger 
as described below

what I want is whenever I insert a row into followers table with followersId and followingId I want those same Id's to be inserted in Notification tables userId and NotifiersId repectively , but what I can find after searching alot is just LAST_INSERT_ID  which is not applicable in my case since I have my primary key as non incremental .

Is there any way where in I can get the values of followersId and followingId of last entered or last updated tuple in followersTable.

**My trigger definition**

```
drop trigger if exists `followNotifyTrigger` ;

delimiter $$
CREATE trigger  followNotifyTrigger 


after insert on followers
for each row 
Begin
declare newUserId int(11);
declare newNotifiersId int(11);

select new.followersId ,New.followingId 
into newUserId , newNotifiersId 
from followers 
where followersId = LAST_INSERT_ID ;

insert into  Notification(typeId,userId,notifiersId,time) values   (1,newUserId,newNotifiersId,NOW());
END $$
DELIMITER ; //
```

**Followers table description**

```
followersId int(11) NO  PRI     
followingId int(11) NO  PRI     
response    bit(1)  NO      b'0'
```

**Notification table description**

```
notificationId  int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
typeId  int(11) YES MUL     
userId  int(11) YES MUL     
notifiersId int(11) YES         
time    datetime    YES
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found solution for my query . It is not better to use trigger since while handling 2 tables one entry might go in one table and other might not go . So best way is to use transaction with stored procedures .

**SOLUTION**

```
USE `dbname`;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `followNotifyUser`;



DELIMITER $$
USE `dbname` $$

CREATE PROCEDURE followNotifyUser(IN followersId int(11),
IN followingId int(11),
IN response bit,
OUT message varchar(255))
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
COMMENT 'Adds "nson" to first and last names in the record.'
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlexception
    BEGIN
    SET message = "mysql exception";
    ROLLBACK ;

    END;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR sqlwarning
    BEGIN 
        SET message = "mysql warnnings";
    ROLLBACK;
    END;

START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO followers(followersId,followingId,response) VALUES (followersId,followingId,response);
INSERT INTO Notification(typeId,userId,notifiersId,time)VALUES(1,followersId,followingId,NOW());
COMMIT;  
END $$
```